# Laravel - Eloquent many to many

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho essa estrutura

Migration da tabela Exercicio

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('exercicio', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nome')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->time('deleted_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Migration da tabela Musculatura

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('musculatura', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nome')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->time('deleted_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Migration da tabela associativa entre Exercicio_Musculatura

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('exercicio_musculatura', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('exercicio_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('exercicio_id')->references('id')->on('exercicio')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('musculatura_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('musculatura_id')->references('id')->on('musculatura')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Model da Tabela Exercicio

```
use SoftDeletes;
public $timestamps  = true;
protected $table    = 'exercicio';
protected $fillable = ['nome'];
protected $dates    = ['deleted_at'];
//Aqui é o método que retorna todos os exercicios com suas respectivas musculaturas pré cadastradas no banco
//o método vai buscar no segundo parametro deste return "na tabela associativa exercicio_musculatura"
public function musculaturas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Http\Models\Musculatura", "Exercicio_Musculatura");
}
public function aparelhos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Http\Models\Aparelho", "Exercicio_Aparelho");
}
```

Model da Tabela Musculatura

```
use SoftDeletes;
public $timestamps  = true;
protected $table    = 'exercicio';
protected $fillable = ['nome'];
protected $dates    = ['deleted_at'];
//Aqui é o método que retorna todos os exercicios com suas respectivas musculaturas pré cadastradas no banco
//o método vai buscar no segundo parametro deste return "na tabela associativa exercicio_musculatura"
public function musculaturas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Http\Models\Musculatura", "Exercicio_Musculatura");
}
public function aparelhos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Http\Models\Aparelho", "Exercicio_Aparelho");
}
```

Model da Tabela associativa da Exercicio_Musculatura

```
class Exercicio_Musculatura extends Model
{

}
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Estou na controller, e recebendo de um AJAX o ID da musculatura de outro lugar, e quero consultar todos os exercicios referentes aquela musculatura, meu banco já tem na tabela associativa os id's bem certinho. Não estou conseguindo retornar nada na minha consulta, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Como está a consulta que não está dando certo? posta por favor

Comment: DB::('exercicio')->where('id', "=", $musculatura_id)->with('musculaturas')->get();

Comment: Estou tentando fazer esta consulta em uma controller

Comment: É mais interessante você utilizar a classe dos models em vez da classe 'DB'. Porém há alguns erros, vou tentar formular uma resposta aqui e você testa se funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No model de exercício:

```
public function musculaturas()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany("App\Http\Models\Musculatura", "exercicio_musculatura", "exercicio_id", "musculatura_id");
}
```

No Model de musculatura:

```
public function exercicios()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany("App\Http\Models\Exercicio", "exercicio_musculatura", "musculatura_id", "exercicio_id");
}
```

No controller você pode fazer a busca:

```
//busca a musculatura pelo id
$musculatura = Musculatura::find($musculatura_id);
//carrega os relacionamentos
$musculatura->load('exercicios');
```

Lembrando que para usar a classe do model Musculatura você tem que dar um use logo abaixo do namespace da classe do seu controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Models\Musculatura;
```

Primeiro erro cometido: no model o nome das tabelas está diferente, na migration está `exercicio_musculatura` e no model está Exercicio_Musculatura. A função belongsToMany recebe como parâmetros o model do relacionamento, o nome da tabela pivô, a chave estrangeira que pertence ao model, e a chave do outro model do relacionamento.

Segundo, os relacionamentos são do eloquent (ou seja entre Models), é interessante usar a classe dos models. Além disso você estava buscando através da sua na tabela de exercícios pelo id da musculatura.

Outra coisa que notei que o Model de Musculaturas tem como nome de tabela 'exercicio':

`protected $table = 'exercicio';`

O nome da tabela deve ser conforme está no banco:
`protected $table = 'musculatura';`

Testa ai, e qualquer coisa consulte a documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Cara deu certo, muito obrigado viu! Muito obrigado mesmo!